# DDA Line Drawing Algorithm has errors

Tags: c, opengl, opengl-3

Why am I getting an error saying 'setPixel not defined' with this code?

```
#include <windows.h>    
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <math.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include<GL/glut.h>

inline int round(const float a)
{
    return int (a+0.5);
}

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    gluOrtho2D(0.0,200.0,0.0,200.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
}

void LineSegment(int xa, int ya,int xb,int yb)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);    

    printf("Enter the initial value");
    scanf("%d%d",&xa,&ya);

    printf("Enter the final value");
    scanf("%d%d",&xb,&yb);

    int dx=xb-xa;
    int dy=yb-ya;
    int steps,k;
    float xIncrement,yIncrement,x=xa,y=ya;
    if(fabs(dx)>fabs(dy))
        steps=fabs(dx);
    else
        steps=fabs(dy);

    xIncrement=dx/(float)steps;
    yIncrement=dy/(float)steps;
    setPixel(round(x),round(y));
    for(k=0;k<steps;k++);
    {
        x += xIncrement;
        y += yIncrement;
        setPixel(round(x),round(y));
    }
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGBA);
    glutCreateWindow("DDA Line Algorithm");
    glutDisplayFunc(LineSegment);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no `setPixel` method in OpenGL or GLUT and as far as I can see from your code, you do not define one either. OpenGL deals with rendering primitives like points, lines, triangels etc, but not directly with setting single pixels on the screen. Since it is unclear what you want to achieve some suggestions:

- If you want to draw a line in OpenGL, use the appropriate methods  like `glBegin(GL_LINES), etc.` (although they are deprecated and should not be used anymore.) or `glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, ...`.
- If the goal is to implement a dda software rasterizer, then you might have to write the pixels to a texture and then display this texture.

Answer (score 2):

Because you haven't defined `setPixel` anywhere. It's not an OpenGL call. You need to write it yourself, and it should set pixels on a buffer (if you're using double buffering) which you then later use as an argument to `glDrawPixels()`, or a call to the display buffer using `glVertex2i(x,y)`. You can see an example of both approaches [here](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~nurmi/cs60/project4/basic.cpp) and [here](http://cse.csusb.edu/tongyu/courses/cs420/notes/bresen.php).

Also, your `LineSegment` function is broken. In OpenGL you call `glutDisplayFunc` to specify a function which is called **as fast as possible** to render the display. However, in this function you call `scanf()` to prompt the user for data - this is broken. You should prompt them once at the start, and then pass that data into the function (which will then run as often as possible once `glutMainLoop` is called).